# List clients attempting to connect to ServerSocket prior to accepting a TCP connection?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming, serversocket

I'm using [`ServerSocket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) in order to listen to the network for clients that are attempting to connect. In other words, I call [`ServerSocket.accept()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()) to "find" the clients. This immediately establishes a TCP connection, which has proven to be somewhat troublesome.

The purpose of the established connection in my case is to use it to start some protocol's specific handshake from my side (server side). Unfortunately this handshake needs to be approved by a user (also server side). This means that the connection may remain open and idling for an arbitrary amount of time prior to being consumed, sort of like a telephone call on hold.

For some reason some clients (which I have no control of) start a timeout as soon as the connection is established (despite the fact that this protocol's specification says nothing about timeouts or the server starting the handshake in a timely fashion). So what currently happens is that, even though the handshake starts successfully, somewhere in the middle it may fail because server side waited too long to finish the authentication phase of the protocol.

Is there a way to list inbound client connections in human readable form without accepting and therefore creating a TCP connection, so one could hand pick a single one of them to accept? If not via `ServerSocket`, perhaps some other way?

Related: would it be considered usual practice to achieve "server side connection filtering" by first blindly accepting the inbound connection and then deciding at some later arbitrary point in time whether to dismiss or actually use the connection? I don't see how `ServerSocket` could be used in any other way.

Comment: Could you accept the connection, but not actually send anything to the clients until approved by the user?  Re:your related, I think most if not all server "blindly" accepting connections (unless blocked by a firewall or something) and use their own protocol to decide whether to continue.

Comment: @Steve, already not sending anything, but it does not matter to some clients. Simply establishing the connection triggers their timeout.

Comment: I think you'll need to implement something in your protocol, e.g. sending a certain byte means "please stand by".

Comment: @Steve, I would, but this is a standard protocol, where no such behavior is defined. I think the client timeout is already non-standard.